# How do I convert a date in an html table cell to iso 8601 format?

Tags: javascript, html, iso8601

I have this td:

```
<td>Jul 18 2019 12:00AM</td>
```

and I need to convert it to ISO 8601 format using JavaScript. Vanilla or using jQuery would be fine, it's just that I keep getting an 'undefined' when I attempt to parse it, but I think it is having trouble because of the html tags. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
 $(function () {
  $("#_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses3 tbody tr td:nth-child(7)").each(function (index, dateElem) {
    var $dateElem = $(dateElem);
    var formatted = moment($dateElem.text(), 'MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').format('MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').toISOString(); 
    $dateElem.text(formatted);   })
 })
```

Comment: Are all dates on your table of this format? You will need to do some string manipulation in order to parse it as a Date Object

Comment: ```var classydate = document.querySelector("#_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(7)").innerText;
moment(classydate,'MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').toISOString();

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to parse it to the custom date string format and then convert it to iso format
For more details regarding [isoString](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)

```
moment('Jul 18 2019 12:00AM','MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').toISOString()
```

Comment: ```
   var classydate = document.querySelector("#_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(7)").innerText;
```
Produces the format I need. How can I iterate through an html table that looks like this:
```
<tr class="TableCellNormal" style="color:Black;background-color:White;">
   <td></td>
   <td align="center">Mar 30 2019 12:00AM</td>
   <td>Mar 30 2019 12:00AM</td>
</tr>
```
?